# Laravel query get items past half the deadline

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a project where orders are posted and have the fields but not limited to those listed below.

```
 Order
 - id
 - name
 - *created_at*
 - *delivery_deadline*
```

Kindly guys help me with how I can query using Laravel Eloquent to get those deliveries past half the deadline i.e. Carbon::now() - created_at > delivery_deadline - Carbon::now().

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried yourself to get it working?

Comment: I think voting down my question didn't benefit you. I believe my question is straight forward and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot think of a way to achieve the requirement purely using Eloquent models because my first thougt is that the data needs pre-processing, i.e. working out the mid of deadlines, before you can do query.

I chose to pre-process the data in SQL, so the following solution utilises the query builder.

The main idea is to use MySql functions `TIMESTAMPADD()` and `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` to find out the mid of deadlines, save them to a temporary table, and finally compare with current datetime.

```php
class Order extends Model
{
    public static function findPassedMidOfDeadlines(): array
    {
        DB::statement('create temporary table if not exists `tmp_mid_deadlines` as (select id, TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created_at, delivery_deadline) DIV 2), created_at) as mid from order)');

        return DB::select(DB::raw('select id from tmp_mid_deadlines where mid < NOW()'));
    }
}
```